# dictonary requeiers a model item of type system.collections.generic.ienumeruble

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have model that one of the fields is TimeInClub
I'm trying to `group by` a table per `TimeInClub`
but I'm getting error

> dictonary requeiers a model item of type system.collections.generic.ienumeruble

The code in the controller is

```
public class FansController : Controller
{
    private dbFan db = new dbFan();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var group = from f in db.fans
                    group f by f.TimeInClub;

        return View(group);
    }
```

In the view I have (my model called Fans my db-context called fans)

```
@model IEnumerable<fan_Club.Models.Fans>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You say you're *grouping* by "TimeInClub", do you actually want to *order* by "TimeInClub? How is this being presented in your view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because the type you return and the type of `@model` are not the same. The result of a `GroupBy` is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>` and not `IEnumerable<fan_Club.Models.Fans>`. You must project to a type that fits the `@model` or change the `@model`

---

If you want to `OrderBy` as David suggested in his comment then:

```
var group = from f in db.fans
            orderby f.TimeInClub 
            select f;
```

*To order it by descending order add the `descending` keyword:*

```
orderby f.TimeInClub descending
```

Comment: thanks for the help i need to use group by, can i convert groupby that the return be like its needed?

Comment: @user7024226 -  But then what is the point of grouping it? Basically the question is what is the data you want to return? What is the purpose of this query?

Comment: the order by give the same effect that i need but i need to use groupby (per my lecture request) to group all the ppl that the time in the club is the same

Comment: @user7024226 - but after you group it what do you need? `GroupBy` is relevant when you want to perform some operations on each group desperately

Comment: ok, i m changging my question i want to group by Name and to count the occurrences

Comment: and i need 2 colmuns Name and sum of occurrences

Comment: @user7024226 - This is a [follow-up question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19457). Unfortunately it will be confusing for future users if I now answer the old-new question. Please post a new question where you specify it. If you comment notify me I will be glad to help. As for this current question - the answer above answers it and I will very appreciate if you mark as solved

Comment: @user7024226 - you are welcome :) And comment me - I'll try to help :)